# useEffect is not Triggering first time

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

```js
 import React, { FC, useEffect } from "react"
 import YouTube from "components/YouTube"
 import { Typography } from "@mui/material"
 import { Container } from "layouts/Player/emotion"
 import Box from "@mui/material/Box"
 import VideoGrid from "components/VideoGrid"
 import { getPlayLists, getUser } from "utils"
 import { VideoCardProps } from "types/ComponentProps"
 import { getVideoById } from "api/youtube"
 import { IYouTubeVideo } from "types/YouTube"

 interface VideoValues {
     embedHTML: string
     title: string
     description: string
 }

 const Player: FC<{ videoId: string }> = ({ videoId }) => {
     const user = getUser()
     const [playlists, setPlaylists] = React.useState<VideoCardProps[]>([])
     const [video, setVideo] = React.useState<VideoValues>({
         embedHTML: "",
         title: "",
         description: "",
     })

     async function initialize() {
         const playlistTemp = await getPlayLists(user.playlist)
         const videoTemp: IYouTubeVideo = await getVideoById(videoId as string)
         setVideo({
             embedHTML: videoTemp.items[0].player.embedHtml,
             title: videoTemp.items[0].snippet.title,
             description: videoTemp.items[0].snippet.description,
         })
         setPlaylists(playlistTemp)
     }

     useEffect(() => {
         initialize()

         console.log("useEffect called")
     }, [])

     return (
         <Container>
             <Box>
                 <YouTube embedHtml={video?.embedHTML} title={video?.title} />
                 <Typography variant={"h5"} fontWeight={"600"}>
                     {video?.title}
                 </Typography>
                 <Typography variant={"body1"}>{video.description}</Typography>
             </Box>

             <Box>
                 <VideoGrid videos={playlists} />
             </Box>
         </Container>
     )
 }

 export default Player
```

In this code snippet, `useEffect` is skipped when the components are rendered, I don't know why. Can you please tell me what's the mistake I am doing here?

When I hardcode YouTube Component Props it works fine and useEffect is also executed. But the issue starts when I fetch video from API CALL

**`useEffect` Not even Triggering first time**

Comment: Put the console log above the call to initialize  , see if that changes things.. no console errors?

Comment: I already have tried that, but its not working

Comment: React hooks, i.e. the `useEffect` hook, are ***guaranteed*** to be called ***at least once***, on the initial render. I doubt React is broken and skipping the `useEffect` callback call when the component mounts. Are there any errors that are preventing the `useEffect` callback from completing? Could you fix the stack snippet to make it runnable or create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue you are seeing that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: the application is connected with my custom backend, which is on localhost. so i doubt it won't be easy to setup with codesandbox but I can share the github repo
[my-tube](https://github.com/darabahmed37/mytube-frontend/tree/yt-linking)

Comment: React hooks don't have much of anything to do with backend code. You need only create a [mcve].

Comment: okay I'll do that

Comment: yes I an binding correctly

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-kilby-1eifyc?file=/src/App.tsx
Link to codesandbox

Comment: could you please try moving your async initialize function inside useEffect?

Comment: _"Link to codesandbox"_... I think you missed the **minimal** part

Comment: sorry this is my 1st time on StackOverflow and code sandbox too
ill fix it

Comment: I tried this out and it seems like there is no issue with react. The only thing coming to my mind you are not showing logs in your developer tools. To find out if this is the case there are two things you can do:
1. Trying another browser
2. Changing your developer tools log settings. @DarabAhmed

Comment: @Agil Atakishiyev thanks but now issue is solved as mentioned below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regular old effect hook dependency problem.

You will note that with standard linting, your effect hook will be complaining about missing dependencies...

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'initialize'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

Were you to follow that advice though, you would see a new error

> The 'initialize' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'initialize' in its own useCallback() Hook.

If you then moved `initialize` into the effect hook, you would see

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'videoId'.

Which leads us to the root cause of all your problems... nothing is set to react to changes to the `videoId` prop.

```ts
useEffect(() => {
  async function initialize() {
    const playlistTemp = await getPlayLists();
    const videoTemp: IYouTubeVideo = await getVideoById(videoId);
    setVideo({
      embedHTML: videoTemp.items[0].player.embedHtml,
      title: videoTemp.items[0].snippet.title,
      description: videoTemp.items[0].snippet.description,
    });
    setPlaylists(playlistTemp);
  }

  console.log("useEffect called");

  initialize();
}, [videoId]);
```

**TL;DR** never ignore warnings. They exist so you don't shoot yourself in the foot.